# GridView control with two asp:Command columns using the same command

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an ASP.NET `GridView` control with two `asp:CommandField` columns that are both using the Select command to perform different tasks.  How do I distinguish which column was selected in the `OnRowCommand` event when both return "Select" when I check the `CommandName` property of the `GridViewCommandEventArgs` object?

Here is my source code:

ASPX page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="MyGridView_OnRowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowSelectButton="true" SelectText="Click Me!" />
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowSelectButton="true" SelectText="No Click Me!" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void MyGridView_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string x = e.CommandName //returns "Select" for both asp:CommandField columns
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a button column instead that way you can specify the specific command names and work with it from there

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" Text="Click Me" CommandName="MyCommand1" />
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" Text="No Click Me" CommandName="MyCommand2" />
```

Then you can take action based on e.CommandName

Comment: I tried the CommandName property and got the following error: Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandField' does not have a public property named 'CommandName'

Comment: you have to create it dynamically to do this.

Comment: look at the answer i gave above.

Comment: @Michael - Make sure you are using my updated example  It is a ButtonColumn

Comment: @Eric YOu do not have to create anything dynamically to use it, you just have to use a ButtonColumn instead.

Comment: @Mitch - Still does not work.  I get the following compilation error: Cannot create an object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonType' from its string representation 'LinkButton' for the 'ButtonType' property.

Comment: @Michael - Oops, I had the syntax down for a DataGrid, I updated the example with the proper value for a GridView.

Comment: @Mitch - the example with produce the first compilation error mentioned in my first comment

Comment: @Michael - No, if you copy/paste my example it works as is.  Your first error was from a different script that I had.  I just re-edited the post, that has been pulled from a working test app.

Comment: Thanks, I switch from an asp:CommandField column to an asp:ButtonField column

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with the early posts!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [GridViewCommandEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcommandeventargs.aspx).CommandArgument property !

Comment: the CommandArgument property return the index of which row was selected.  I need to know which asp:commandfield was selected within the row.

Comment: No, the CommandArgument returns whatever argument you specify. So you can have buttons with the same CommandName, but different Arguments. This helps you identify which button raised the command.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first do you HAVE to use SELECt as the command?  You could set that to something else that makes more sense.

Secondly, you could set the CommandArgument property to different values so you know which one is being clicked.

Comment: Well, it makes sense to use the Select command because I am not performing any CRUD operations on the record.  Both scenarios just require an informational query.

Comment: But a command could be anything.  It could be select_one or select_two for instance...

Comment: The whole purpose of my question is trying to determine if there is a way to indicate that select_one was clicked.

Comment: Yes, and you can set the command name to select_one.  Or you could set the CommandArgument property to One.  Either way you can check to see which command was clicked...

Answer (score 0):

use the command argument property.

```
e.commandargument
```

Or you can dynamically create the button in the command field and set the commandName to anything you want.

in gridview_Load

```
for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {

    linkbutton btnedit = new linkbutton();


    GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Controls.Add(btnedit);
   //the above is where you want the button to be on the grid
    btndel.CommandName = "Select2";
    btndel.CommandArgument = "whatever you want";
}

Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Select1" Then 

       //do stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: The manual addition of the link is overkill in this users situation, and requires a secondary traversal of the grid items which isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you seek is simple and tricky. I had that problem too in my website project, so I surfed the internet for days and not found what I and you were needed.

One day I just thought about the problem alone and made experiments for hours and finally realized that the only easy way to know the column that the button was clicked is in the `RowCommand event` of the `GridView` in the `CommandName property` of the `GridViewCommandEventArgs`. More correctly probably and comfortable is to edit columns of `GridView` through the design mode and replace your Command fields to Button fields.

You can give any `string/text` you want to each button field in its `CommandName`, so in the `RowCommand` event you can know which was clicked. `Button1` or `Button2`, but you don't want to give these strings, because you request something that the buttons should select and give to you, so the `CommandName` should be the word **select**, but it can be **SELECT** too and **Select** and **selecT** and etc.

The select command can be mention in the `CommandName` in many forms, and still the system will recognize it. So for example if you have two **Button** fields in the `GridView`, whose first `CommandName` is simply **select** and the other is **SELECT**, then when any of them is clicked the `RowCommand` event raises and

```
if (e.CommandName == "select")
  { 
   Label1.Text = "You clicked first button";
  }
  else 
  {
   Label1.Text = "You clicked second button";
  }
```

and the `SelectedDataKey` of your `GridView` will contains the data you requested. What other people offered in their answer to differ in `CommandName` by setting button one to `select_one` and setting button two to `select_two` will help you to know if either `select_one` was clicked or other, but the `SelectedDataKey` of your `GridView` will remain `null` or `DataKey` instance that doesn't contain the information you need at all.

In other words, the buttons will not select any necessary information, so it is very important to follow **my** answer. It is the exact, perfect and great solution to your problem!